# Workaround for Heroku 30 second timeout w/ long external query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Note: There are going to be things in this post which are less-than-best-practices.  Be warned :)

- I'm working on an admin dashboard which connects to a micro-instance AWS server.
- The DB has tens of millions of records.
- Most queries come back within a few seconds but some take up to a minute or two to return, based on a few things outside of my control.

Due to Heroku's 30-second limit (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout), I need to find some way to buy time to keep the connection open until the query returns.  Heroku does say that you can buy time by sending bytes to the client in the meantime, which buys you another 55 seconds.

Anyways, just curious if you guys have a solution to stall time for Heroku.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break down the thing into multiple queries.

You may send a query, have your AWS server respond immediately just saying that it received query and then once it pulls the data, have it send that data via a POST request to your Heroku instance.

Comment: thanks, i'll accept the answer but if you're bored, a code sample would help :)

Comment: What I described is merely a webhook - see the presentation at http://www.slideshare.net/progrium/using-web-hooks.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a workaround for this. Our app is running Sinatra and I have used [EventMachine gem](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) to keep writing `\0` into stream every 10 seconds so Heroku doesn't close connection until action is complete, see the example https://gist.github.com/troex/31790323fb4a8a29c8b8cd84e50ad1e8

My example is using Puma but it should work for Unicorn and Thin as well (you don't need `EventMachine.run` for Thin). For Rails I think you can use before/after_action to start/stop event timer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do it via ajax, send back a response that says ask again in a bit...