# How can I get around Heroku's HTTP 30 second limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud9-ide, puma

I inherited a rails app that is deployed using Heroku (I think). I edit it on AWS's Cloud9 IDE and, for now, just do everything in development mode. The app's purpose is to process large amounts of survey data and spit it out onto a PDF report. This works for small reports with like 10 rows of data, but when I load a report that is querying a data upload of 5000+ rows to create an HTML page which gets converted to a PDF, it takes around 105 seconds, much longer than Heroku's 30 seconds allotted for HTTP requests.

Heroku says this on their website, which gave me some hope:

"Heroku supports HTTP 1.1 features such as long-polling and streaming responses. An application has an initial 30 second window to respond with a single byte back to the client. However, each byte transmitted thereafter (either received from the client or sent by your application) resets a rolling 55 second window. If no data is sent during the 55 second window, the connection will be terminated." (Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#long-polling-and-streaming-responses)

This sounds excellent to me - I can just send a request to the client every second or so in a loop until we're done creating the large PDF report. However, I don't know how to send or receive a byte or so to "reset the rolling 55 second window" they're talking about.

Here's the part of my controller that is sending the request.

```
            return render pdf: pdf_name + " " + pdf_year.to_s,
                disposition: 'attachment',
                page_height: 1300,
                encoding: 'utf8',
                page_size:   'A4',
                footer: {html: {template: 'recent_grad/footer.html.erb'}, spacing: 0 },
                margin:  {   top:    10,                     # default 10 (mm)
                            bottom: 20,
                            left:   10,
                            right:  10 },
                template: "recent_grad/report.html.erb",
                locals: {start: @start, survey: @survey, years: @years, college: @college, department: @department, program: @program, emphasis: @emphasis, questions: @questions}
```

I'm making other requests to get to this point, but I believe the part that is causing the issue is here where the template is being rendered. My template queries the database in a finite loop that stops when it runs out of survey questions to query from.

My question is this: how can I "send or receive a byte to the client" to tell Heroku "I'm still trying to create this massive PDF so please reset the timer and give me my 55 seconds!" Is it in the form of a query? Because, if so, I am querying the MySql database over and over again in my report.html.erb file.

Also, it used to work without issues and does work on small reports, but now I get the error "504 Gateway Timeout" before the request is complete on the actual page, but my puma console continues to query the database like a mad man. I assume it's a Heroku problem because the 504 error happens exactly every 35 seconds (5 seconds to process the other parts and 30 seconds to try to finish the loop in the template so it can render correctly).

If you need more information or code, please ask! Thanks in advance

EDIT: 
Both of the comments below suggest possible duplicates, but neither of them have a real answer with real code, they simply refer to the docs that I am quoting here. I'm looking for a code example (or at least a way to get my foot in the door), not just a link to the docs. Thanks!

EDIT 2:

I tried what @Sergio said and installed SideKiq. I think I'm really close, but still having some issues with the worker. The worker doesn't have access to ActionView::Base which is required for the render method in rails, so it's not working. I can access the worker method which means my sidekiq and redis servers are running correctly, but it gets caught on the ActionView line with this error:

WARN: NameError: uninitialized constant HardWorker::ActionView

Here's the worker code:

```
require 'sidekiq'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  # config.redis = { db: 1 }
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://172.31.6.51:6379/0' }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  # config.redis = { db: 1 }
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://172.31.6.51:6379/0' }
end  

class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(pdf_name, pdf_year)
    av = ActionView::Base.new()
    av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths
    av.class_eval do
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
      include ApplicationHelper
    end
    puts "inside hardworker"
    puts pdf_name, pdf_year

    av.render pdf: pdf_name + " " + pdf_year.to_s,
                disposition: 'attachment',
                page_height: 1300,
                encoding: 'utf8',
                page_size:   'A4',
                footer: {html: {template: 'recent_grad/footer.html.erb'}, spacing: 0 },
                margin:  {   top:    10,                     # default 10 (mm)
                            bottom: 20,
                            left:   10,
                            right:  10 },
                template: "recent_grad/report.html.erb",
                locals: {start: @start, survey: @survey, years: @years, college: @college, department: @department, program: @program, emphasis: @emphasis, questions: @questions}
  end
end
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT 3: 
I did what @Sergio said and attempted to make a PDF from an html.erb file directly and save it to a file. Here's my code:

```
# /app/controllers/recentgrad_controller.rb

pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_html_file('home/ec2-user/environment/gradSurvey/gradSurvey/app/views/recent_grad/report.html.erb')
            save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs', pdf_name + pdf_year.to_s + '.pdf')
            File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
              file << pdf
            end
```

And the error output:

```
RuntimeError (Failed to execute:
["/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@gradSurvey/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "file:///home/ec2-user/environment/gradSurvey/gradSurvey/app/views/recent_grad/report.html.erb", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20190523-15416-hvb3zg.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: Loading pages (1/6)
Error: Failed loading page file:///home/ec2-user/environment/gradSurvey/gradSurvey/app/views/recent_grad/report.html.erb (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
):
```

I have no idea what it means when it says "sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore". The file definitely exists and I've tried maybe 5 variations of the file path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Workaround for Heroku 30 second timeout w/ long external query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057829/workaround-for-heroku-30-second-timeout-w-long-external-query)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I workaround heroku's 30 sec timeout when executing long PLSQL procedure in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854166/how-can-i-workaround-herokus-30-sec-timeout-when-executing-long-plsql-procedure)

Comment: See edit above, I am looking for how to do this, not just where to find them in the docs. It seems the other two posts are merely pointing the questioners to the docs that I referenced in my question.

Comment: "My template queries the database in a finite loop that stops when it runs out of survey questions to query from." - I smell a case of N+1 here

Comment: It turned out to work when I inherited from ApplicationJob in a job, not a worker, although they are essentially the same thing. Here's my inheritance: ```class CreatePdfJob < ApplicationJob```. The real winner here is @unixmonkey who maintains wicked_pdf for rails, and he set up a working app for me. You can see the question here: github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/835 And the commit that really changed the way it worked can be viewed here: github.com/unixmonkey/generate_pdf_async_example/commit/… Enjoy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had to do something like this several times. In all cases, I ended up writing a background job that does all the heavy <strike>lifting</strike> generation. And because it's not a web request, it's not affected by the 30 seconds timeout. It goes something like this:

1. client (your javascript code) requests a new report.
2. server generates job description and enqueues it for your worker to pick up.
3. worker picks the job from the queue and starts working (querying database, etc.)
4. in the meanwhile, client periodically asks the server "is my report done yet?". Server responds with "not yet, try again later"
5. worker is finished generating the report. It uploads the file to some storage (S3, for example), sets job status to "completed" and job result to the download link for the uploaded report file.
6. server, seeing that job is completed, can now respond to client status update requests "yes, it's done now. Here's the url. Have a good day."
7. Everybody's happy. And nobody had to do any streaming or playing with heroku's rolling response timeouts.

The scenario above uses short-polling. I find it the easiest to implement. But it is, of course, a bit wasteful with regard to resources. You can use long-polling or websockets or other fancy things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sergio. I understand the concept, but am not sure how to implement it. How do I tell a worker what to do? And what is a worker? Sorry for my noob questions, I'm still pretty new to Rails and development in general.

Comment: @Parzival: "How do I tell a worker what to do?" - it's called [ActiveJob](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html). You can (and should) use another backend for activejob (like [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq))

Comment: It seems like everything is pointing to sidekiq, so I'll try it out and let you know what happened. Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: I'm so close (sidekiq is running and I can hit that method) but I'm still getting an error when trying to use the render method because I'm in a worker. See my "EDIT 2" above. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you create the file, save it on the server, send it back to the user/visitor and then delete it at some point in the future?  i.e. set the appropriate headers to force the file to download.

Comment: @prieber what do you mean? The PDF that is being created is extremely large, so creating one that large requires time (hence the background processing). I am pretty new to programming, so I don't really know how to save it to the server.

Comment: @Parzival No problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24778838/7044855) should help create the file.  The file would still be generated in the background, but you wouldn't have to include try including any of the `ActionView` code.

Comment: Can you show me some code? I get the idea of putting it into pdf_content, but don't know how that would look considering my render was initially just rendering a pdf the wicked pdf way

Comment: @Parzival: scroll wicked_pdf's readme a bit further :) https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#super-advanced-usage

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I was able to use those docs to make a pdf from a string and save it to a file but not make a pdf from a file. See the edit above for the error I get. Please and thank you!

Comment: @Parzival: notice that the method is called `pdf_from_html_file` and what you pass to it is not html. You'll probably have more success by rendering that ERB template by hand. Like [this](https://blog.revathskumar.com/2014/10/ruby-rendering-erb-template.html), for example.

Comment: Anyway, this is getting more and more out of scope.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for your help, I'll mark your answer as correct for now. I appreciate you getting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Check [my response here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68704837/21087) just in case it works for you. I didn´t wanted to change the user workflow adding a bg job and then a place/notification to get the result.
I use Rails controller streaming support with Live module and set the right reponse headers. I fetch the data from some Enumerable object.